# Solaris: Encrypting a zpool NOT a dataset within a pool?

Tags: solaris, zfs, zpool

What is the way in Solaris to encrypt a zpool? All the documentation supporting ZFS encryption talk about using "zfs create" and specifying a dataset WITHIN a pool. I just became SA for several Solaris servers and they all have encrypted zpools, but no documentation as to how they get that way. I know its possible since these servers have their pools configured with encryption, with no datasets on them. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know the zpools are encrypted?

Comment: I ran "zfs get encryption" and it shows the property as "on" for the zpool which contains no datasets.

Comment: yes, this command shows the pool as unencrypted and data set encrypted. "zfs set encryption=on poolname" -> cannot set property for 'poolname': 'encryption' is readonly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to create the pool with encryption enabled for its top dataset:

```
zpool create -O encryption=on ...
```

Comment: Sigh... If only we had this for *non-Solaris* ZFS implementations...